# Dynamic primevue ProgressBar

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I want to use a ProgressBar in a vue application such that the value of the ProgressBar is dynamically updated over time.

```
<ProgressBar :value="value"></ProgressBar>
```

How can we update the value over time?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the example in the official documentation show just that? https://primevue.org/progressbar/#:~:text=Value%20is%20reactive%20so%20updating%20it%20dynamically%20changes%20the%20bar%20as%20well.

Comment: I tried it, but the value does not update!

Comment: I could update it eventually. Thanks